# Terraform AWS API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am new to terraform and i´m creating API Gateway.

My api gateway will have 4 resources and each one will have a POST method. I would like to know if it is possible to use a payload validator whith a diferent json for each method.

If yes, how do I do this via terraform?

Follow part of my code

```
`
resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "teste_api"{
    name = var.rest_api_name
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_request_validator" "teste_api" {
  rest_api_id           = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.teste_api.id}"
  name                  = "payload-validator"
  validate_request_body = true
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_model" "teste_api" {
  rest_api_id  = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.teste_api.id}"
  name         = "Payloadteste"
  description  = "validar orders"
  content_type = "application/json"
  schema = <<EOF
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "required": [ "id", "docs"],
  "properties": {
    "id": { "type": "string" },
    "docs": {
      "minItems": 1,
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "object"
      }
    }
  }
}
EOF
}`
```

I would like someone to help me with my code.